# Git: Can I move\merge changes from branch to branch?

Tags: git

I have the following problem. I assume some of you also have it from time to time:

Sometimes, I forget to create a feature branch and start to make the changes on the master branch.

I still did not commit those changes.

What I do usually is to keep the changes on the side, revert, create the new FB and merge the changes.

Is there a more elegant way to solve this situation?

If it relevant too, I am working with InteliJ, but cmd line solutions are also welcomed.

Comment: I normally `git checkout -b` a feature branch from master, then hard-reset master to appropriate commit (top commit of origin/master, for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have not yet made any commits, then all you have to do is create a new branch at your current location:

```
git checkout -b feature-branch
```

The `git checkout -b` command creates a new branch at your current location (which would be the tip of the master branch for you) and checks out that branch (meaning new commits will be on that branch.) Your work tree remains unchanged. Note that uncommitted changes do not yet belong to any branch. You can continue to work on your feature and commit when ready.

No need to copy your changes anywhere else, nor clear your worktree with `git stash` or `git reset --hard` and copy/merge your changes back in.

Answer (score 2):

The better approach would be execute the following commands.

**Switch** to your feature-branch or **creates and switch** to it if the branch doesn't exist.

```
git checkout -b feature-branch
```

If you want to save your changes on your feature-branch so it belongs to it:

```
git add . # Stage the file for commit to your local repository.
git commit -m "Add comment" # Commit the file that you've staged in your local repository.
git push origin feature-branch # Push the changes in your local repository to GitHub.
```

To clean your branch if you don't want to keep the changes you did not commit, you can use the following command.

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

It will erase all changes in your working tree, so that your current files match the content of the HEAD.

Comment: no need to `git reset --hard`. He wants these changes...but in the feature branch instead of master. He can commit after creating the `feature-branch` with the `git checkout -b feature-branch` command.

Comment: He has not yet committed anything. All changes are in his work tree only. That means they are not on any branch. After executing `git checkout -b feature-branch` all future commits will go on the feature branch. All he has to do after the checkout command is commit. No need to clean or reset the work tree. @LuVu

Comment: I understand that.  But dushkin has said he wants to KEEP his changes. He wants to commit them on a feature branch, and not `master`. In order to do that, he has to `git checkout -b feature-branch` followed by `git commit <files>`.  His change will go onto the feature branch and not `master`. @LuVu

Comment: Note that any uncommitted changes in the work tree do NOT belong to any branch. Whether a user makes changes and then executes `git checkout -b <branch>` or executes the command first and then makes changes makes no difference. When he commits, the commits will go on <branch>. @LuVu @dushkin

Answer (score 1):

When this happens, if it is not a problem to point a revision to an earlier revision (which can a problem if you have already pushed the dev branch), you can do this:

```
git checkout -b my-feature-branch # create feature branch right where I am right now
git branch -f dev HEAD~10 # set dev 10 revisions behind.... you could also use a revision ID instead of HEAD~x
```

And that's it.

Comment: This would be the correct answer if the user has already made one or more commits erroneously on the `dev` branch  (before pushing). But the user stated `I still did not commit those changes.` With this provision, the second command is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

For storing changes: `git stash .`
For unstash: `git stash pop`